# Deserialize partial JSON

Tags: c#, json.net, json-deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize some partial JSON received from an old SignalR service.

This is an example of the original JSON:

```js
{
  "opt": {
    "data": {
      "DR": [{
          "O": [
            null,
            "18:46.401",
            "RGGW.GWWWR",
            "4.1",
            19,
            "17.852",
            "42.455",
            "",
            null,
            "+3.893",
            "277",
            "306",
            "",
            "310",
            "+0.058",
            null
          ],
          "OC": [
            "1"
          ]
        },
        {
          "O": [
            null,
            "1:41.119",
            "GYYG.WWWWW",
            "1.0",
            2,
            "17.561",
            "43.485",
            "40.073",
            null,
            "+16.772",
            "275",
            "291",
            "218",
            "291",
            "+16.772",
            null
          ],
          "OC": [
            "1"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and this the partial JSON received:

```js
{
  "opt": {
    "data": {
      "DR": {
        "1": {
          "O": {
            "2": "WYYW.WWWWW",
            "7": "42.283",
            "12": "212"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and these are my classes:

```
    public class DR2
    {
        [JsonProperty("O")]
        public List<object> O { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("OC")]
        public List<string> OC { get; set; }
    }

    public class Data4
    {
        [JsonProperty("DR")]
        public List<DR2> DR { get; set; }
    }

    public class Opt
    {
        [JsonProperty("data")]
        public Data4 data { get; set; }
    }

    public class SPFeed
    {
        [JsonProperty("opt")]
        public Opt opt { get; set; }
    }
```

Trying to deserialize I receive the classic error:

> JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object ... because the type requires a JSON array.

```
SPFeed partial_opt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SPFeed>(test); // The error above
```

Also, trying to merge the 2 JSON with the code below, no merge made, but only substitution:

```
var object1 = JObject.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(spfeed));
var object2 = JObject.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(partial_opt));



object1.Merge(object2, new JsonMergeSettings
{
    MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Merge
});
```

I think because the partial JSON in not a correct array.
Any other method to deserialize?

Comment: Because property `O` is not an array (`[]`) but an object (`{ ... }`). I presume that the properties inside object `O` are dynamic so you cannot create a class for them. I suggest you change the  `List` to a `Dictionary<string, string>` . (not tested)

Comment: Sounds like you need [a custom `JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm)

Comment: The properties inside O are static (as described in the orginal json received from the SignalR service).

Comment: @babyporch Well in the partial JSON received the O object is not an array while in the first JSON code it could be a `List<string>`

Comment: @HereticMonkey i tested some solutions but with no results. Other solutions? Loop in the partial json to check if DR is present then .... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved:

```
var obj = JObject.Parse(partialJson);
Opt opt = root.SPFeed.opt;
if (obj["opt"]["data"]["DR"] != null) {
        IList<JToken> DR = JObject.Parse(obj["opt"]["data"]["DR"].ToString());
        var DRindex = Convert.ToInt32(((JProperty)DR[0]).Name);
        var O = ((JProperty)DR[0]).Value;

        JToken Otemp = JToken.Parse(O.ToString());

        if (Otemp["O"] != null)
        {
            var Oindex = Otemp["O"];
            foreach (JToken item in Oindex)
            {
                int index = Convert.ToInt32(((JProperty)item).Name);
                string value = ((JProperty)item).Value.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine("Index {0} Value {1}", index, value);
                opt.data.DR[DRindex].O[index] = value;
            }
        }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the cleanest solution, but if you can detect if the JSON is partial or not, then you could use a Custom Contract Resolver. This would also required some changes to your class structure. Redefining structure as

```
public interface IData{}
public class Data4Partial:IData
{
    [JsonProperty("DR")]
    public Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>>> Data{get;set;}
}

public class DR2Full:IData
{
    [JsonProperty("O")]
    public List<object> O { get; set; } 
    [JsonProperty("OC")]
    public List<string> OC { get; set; }
}

public class Data4Full:IData
{
    [JsonProperty("DR")]
    public List<DR2Full> DR { get; set; }
}

public class Opt
{
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public IData data { get; set; }
}

public class SPFeed
{
    [JsonProperty("opt")]
    public Opt opt { get; set; }
}
```

The Contract Resolver would aim to replace the PropertyType so that result could be adapted to Partial and Full Json. For example,

```
public class GenericContractResolver<T> : DefaultContractResolver  
{

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        if (property.UnderlyingName == "data")
        {
            property.PropertyType = typeof(T);
        }
        return property;
    }
}
```

You could now use it as

```
var partialResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SPFeed>(partialJson, new JsonSerializerSettings 
                                       { 
                                         ContractResolver = new GenericContractResolver<Data4Partial>() 
                                       });
```

Or

```
var fullResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SPFeed>(fullJson
                                    , new JsonSerializerSettings 
                                       { 
                                         ContractResolver = new GenericContractResolver<Data4Full>() 
                                       });
```

Partial Json Output
[image]

Complete Json Output

[image]

Comment: It works, but there are a lot of others classes in Opt ecc... and it breaks everything. Basically the fullJson (is more complex) give the full situation, only the partial json sent from the SignalR service, give the arrays in wrong format, ex: "opt": {
      "data": {
        "DR": {
          "9": {
            "O" where 9 is the index of array to update (and there are lots of this type of array)